# Cursor and update in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've written a function in postgresql for updating a table using two cursors, the code executes fine without errors but doesn't do anything.

I have three tables

1. product master
2. sales data table
3. target table

So in the below function I'm getting product key from 1 and then in the sales table calculating no of stores/outlets the product was sold and then update the third table accordingly,

I need to calc the no of outlets for each product every week. but they should be unique, e.g If a product was sold in outlets A and B in first week the no of stores in first week should be 2, if it is sold in B, C, D next week the total should be 4 for 2nd week, If it is sold in A and D in third week the total should be still 4 for 3rd week. How do I do this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
  create or replace function StCount() returns void as
   $BODY$
    Declare
      ik1 integer ; 
    wk1  integer ; 
    Cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT  ik  From table1 ; 
      Cur2   CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct(wk) FROM table2 order by wk asc;


  begin
    OPEN Cur1 ;
   WHILE (Found) Loop 
   FETCH  next from Cur1 INTO ik1  ; 

OPEN Cur2 ;

  WHILE (Found) Loop 
     FETCH  next from Cur2 INTO wk1;    

                update table3 set skly =(select count(sk)from table2 a  
        where a.ik = ik1   and a.wk = wk1  
        and a.sk not in (select distinct (sk) from table2
        where ik = ik1 and wk <= wk1 - 1 ))
        where ik = ik1 and wk = w1
        ;


  End loop ;
CLOSE Cur2;

  end loop ;

   CLOSE Cur1;

  END;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Why are you using cursors in the first place, this can be done much more efficiently with a single update statement (and `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function)

Comment: I'm just selecting distinct values to compare the new number , where do you see I've defined distinct as a function?

Comment: I'm using the cursor since I've to scan the entire table every time to count the value I need , I'm not sure how a single update will accomplish that

Comment: `distinct(wk)` - distinct is not a function. That's the same as `distinct wk`. distinct always operates on all columns in the select list. Putting the columns of the select list in parentheses is useless if it's a single column and plain wrong for multiple columns (plus: the `distinct` inside the sub-query is useless anyway)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the definition of the tables involved, some sample data, and the expected output after the update. I'm sure this can be done without in efficient and slow cursor loops.

Comment: I've posted the question to know why the cursor is not behaving the way it's supposed to and yes for the data in the table I'm selecting from using distinct does make a difference although it is in a subquery

Comment: No. The distinct in a sub-query (for an `IN` condition) **is** useless (and will slow down things)

Comment: I've edited the question , please explain how you can use update in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us how your tables look like or what exactly the data is you are dealing with, so I am assuming a lot here.

Using this setup:

```
create table product (id integer primary key);
create table sales (id serial primary key, product_id integer, store text, wk integer);

insert into product values (1),(2),(3),(4);

insert into sales (product_id, store, wk)
values
  (1, 'A', 1),
  (1, 'B', 1),
  (1, 'B', 2),
  (1, 'C', 2),
  (1, 'D', 2),
  (1, 'A', 3),
  (1, 'D', 3);
```

The cumulative sales per product, store and week can be calculated like this:

```
select product_id, 
       store,
       wk,
       count(store) over (partition by product_id order by wk) as sofar
from (
  select product_id, 
         store, 
         wk,
         row_number() over (partition by product_id, store order by wk) as rn
  from sales
  order by product_id, store
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Note that the `product` table isn't actually used in this, but it can easily be joined to the inner query.

For the above sample data, this returns:

```
product_id | store | wk | sofar
-----------+-------+----+------
         1 | A     |  1 |     2
         1 | B     |  1 |     2
         1 | C     |  2 |     4
         1 | D     |  2 |     4
```

Now this result can be used to update the target table:

```
update target_table
   set slky = t.sofar
from (
    select product_id, 
           store,
           wk,
           count(store) over (partition by product_id order by wk) as sofar
    from (
      select product_id, 
             store, 
             wk,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id, store order by wk) as rn
      from sales
      order by product_id, store
    ) t
    where rn = 1
) s
where s.wk = target_table.wk 
  and s.product_id = target_table.product_id
  and s.store = target_table.store;
```

This assumes that the combination of `(product_id, store, wk)` is unique in `target_table`. As you have obfuscated the names of your tables and columns in your example it is hard to tell though.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it did work. But I'm still not sure where I went wrong with my cursors...